# Backscatter in RFID

Tags: voltage, rf, electromagnetism, modulation, transmitter

I am reading and trying to understand about the RF ID communication.

I read that the receiver conveys the binary data back to the transmitter using backscatter modulation.

But I find it a little difficult to understand how the backscatter communication works and how the RFID reader can act as a transmitter and receiver at all times? Does the reader send the signal for a short period of time as a transmitter and then acts as a receiver?

Would like to understand the backscatter communication in a little more detail. I tried to search to find deeper understanding, but unable to get it anywhere.

Comment: Try [here](http://www.infocomm-journal.com/jcin/EN/abstract/abstract168928.shtml) to start. I think you can download the paper there. It's an overview. Perhaps something useful can be found. (I've no skill in this area. Just an interest in a related topic: *ambient backscatter*.)

Comment: I have the same question you have. Is it the phase that changes? Like imagine the sender sender sends a  1 Hz signal at t=0. And receives a 1 Hz signal back at t=0.1. Well, the first signal has a peak at t=0s, but the returned signal has a peak at t=0.1s.  This must mean the returned signal came from somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

There are several standards and I'm not sure which of them you are refering to.

You find plenty information about the topic in
"RFID Handbook: Fundamentals and Applications in Contactless Smart Cards, Radio Frequency Identification and Near-Field Communication"
by Klaus Finkenzeller (a former colleague of mine ;-).

There is a pdf [extract](http://www.rfid-handbook.de/downloads/G6E_20120413_212413155-24_978-3-446-42992-5_Leseprobe.pdf)
of the German version of the book available in the internet. Maybe it already answers your questions.

Let's look at two of the standards. Only with one of them I'm more familiar.

- **NFC** (Near Field Communication).
  It works at  13.56MHz over distances in the range of up to ca. 10cm or less.
  I.e. it works  clearly in the [near field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field) of the RF.
  It is used with RFID tags and contactless smart cards and it is specified in the [ISO/IEC 14443](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14443) series of standards.

  There ([e.g.](http://www.emutag.com/iso/14443-2.pdf), section "8.2 Communication PICC to PCD") it says communication from card (called PICC) to reader (called IFD) is done by **load modulation**, i.e. the PICC loads its resonant LC circuit used to extract energy from the RF field with the data bit pattern it wants to send to the IFD.

  This is equivalent to the PICC sending its "own" signal phase synchronously to the readers RF field that interferes with the readers RF field.
  So if the IFD "pumps" constant power into the RF field it can detect the PICC's data by measuring the field stength of its own signal,
  e.g. by montoring the voltage in the IFD's TX/RX coil.

  (see extract of the book mentioned above: S. 49 (p. 20 in pdf), Abb. 3.16)

  The IFD **continuously** transmits an RF field (except for very short breaks if 100% ASK is used, see spec) to supply the PICC with **energy**.
  **Data communication**, however, from IFD to PICC and back is **half-duplex**, i.e. only one party is transmitting data (= modulating the RF field) at a time.
- Standards using frequency in the UHF or even microwave range over distances of several meters.
  This is not in the [near field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field) any more and this is where the term "backscatter" makes sense, i.e.
  the signal from the tag (or whaterver device) to reader is seen as a more or less independent signal.
  The reader consists of a transmitter and a receiver and has a [circulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulator)
  to seperate the RF power going out to and coming in from the antenna.

  (see extract of the book mentioned above: S. 58 (p. 29 in pdf), Abb. 3.25)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Curd. This is my understanding - "When the tag is in the magnetic field of the reader, the voltage is induced in the tag and is rectified by the diode and the induced voltage powers the IC. So, when the IC is powered, the load modulation (turning ON or OFF the transistor that is connected to the IC) happens. When this happens, the current drawn by the primary coil increases when the transistor at the tag is turned ON and vice versa. But how are the bits from the tag to the reader are conveyed?" Whether its correct?

Comment: @Newbie: I extended my answer by differentiating between NFC and communication techinques in the RF far-field and added some links to literature.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple magnetically coupled RFID reader, the reader provides the energy to power the RFID tag. So, if you looked at the AC current drawn by the RFID reader's magnetic field generating circuit, you would see a small increase as you brought the tag into the proximity of the reader's magnetic field.

OK so far?

So, if the tag is in the magnetic field and activated, and the tag modulated its own DC current that it draws via its pick-up coil and rectifier, you would also "see" an AC current modulation at the reader. Of course it's only a small change in the AC current seen at the reader but that's enough to be able to reconstruct to modulation imposed by the tag.

That's how a tag communicates back with the reader.

> *Does the reader send the signal for a short period of time as a
> transmitter and then acts as a receiver?*

It has to. The data protocol means that if the reader sends data, it is in the form of a packet and, once that packet is delivered to the tag, the reader awaits a tag response (typically).

Comment: Is what your describe here technically *backscatter* communications? Or is the OP wrong to suggest that RFID technology involves backscatter?

Comment: @jonk on your link, it falls under "B" (categories) on page 4 (passive transmitter).

Comment: Okay. Thanks. In ambient backscatter, there's no energy harvesting or inductive power via magnetic coupling. I'll go check that section tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Table 2, row labeled "passive". Got it. Uses energy harvesting, though. Not what I'm used to when thinking about this. Though energy harvesting is certainly an option with ambient backscatter transmitters, it's not a requirement. They can just be micropower, which is the key as backscatter transmitters don't actually radiate themselves and would have no (US, at least) communications regulatory oversight because all they do is slightly alter the existing fields around them. Thanks, again!

Comment: @Andyaka, thank you for the answer. I have taken some time to understand. This is my understanding - "When the tag is in the magnetic field of the reader, the voltage is induced in the tag and is rectified by the diode and the induced voltage powers the IC. So, when the IC is powered, the load modulation (turning ON or OFF the transistor that is connected to the IC) happens. When this happens, the current drawn by the primary coil increases when the transistor at the tag is turned ON and vice versa. But how are the bits from the tag to the reader are conveyed?"

Comment: @newbie the tag modulates its own current draw and this causes the power input to the reader (primary) to modulate. That modulation IS the data.

Comment: @Andyaka, thank you. So, the tag modulates its own current draw. And the input gets modulated accordingly right. But the input (reader - the source) is just transmitting right? It is not receiving, I mean like - not in the receiver state, to understand the modulation, right?

Comment: The reader is outputting a constant field but the tag is modulating that field hence, the reader can detect that modulation in the field. It can detect it because of small changes in the current drawn in producing what it believes to be a constant field. Yes, the reader needs to have that detection circuitry else it cannot know that there is a modulation caused by the tag @Newbie

Comment: Thank you. So, the detection circuitary would be on and off for some time to detect the modulation?

Comment: @Newbie the reader detection circuit would be on (active) when it is appropriate to be active.